# Using the Microsoft Team Beta API, provisioning Teams

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I have been trying to use the Graph API, beta version, and am able to create an office 365 group , but so far no luck with adding a Microsoft Team to the group.

When i use the beta API i will get a code InvalidRequest, "Calling this API using MSGraph Application Permissions is not supported."

The request i am sending is a PUT with "https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/groups/{id}/team" with id the group id. Also i am sure the bearer token is ok, since other requests such as creating an office 365 group work fine.

Setting delegated permissions in Azure app registration or granting permissions didnt seem to work. Is this a beta issue for now or is there something else i should be looking for?

See the below error as example :

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": "InvalidRequest",
    "message": "Calling this API using MSGraph Application Permissions is 
not supported.",
    "innerError": {
      "request-id": "c4c28d6c-e7f2-4817-bdc7-c5985de61c92",
      "date": "2018-06-19T19:18:22"
    }
  }
}
```

Regards,

Jos Eilers

Answer (score 1):

App-only permissions are not currently supported. It only works with delegated permissions and that too for work or school accounts. Wont work with Personal MS account

At my end, I am making a `PUT` request to the `/beta/groups/<group id>/team` endpoint with the below mentioned payload and it works:

```
{  
  "memberSettings": {
    "allowCreateUpdateChannels": true
  },
  "messagingSettings": {
    "allowUserEditMessages": true,
    "allowUserDeleteMessages": true
  },
  "funSettings": {
    "allowGiphy": true,
    "giphyContentRating": "strict"
  }
}
```

reference - [Create team - Beta documentation](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/beta/api/team_put_teams)